# Failed adding custom icon for add-on button

Tags: scripting, add-on

How I add custom icon for add-on button? I have ready a 32x32 size photo for my icon but dob't know how to add it[image]

I have copy the code of: [How to implement custom icons for my script/addon?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32335/how-to-implement-custom-icons-for-my-script-addon)

But when I run script, it shown this  [image]

Besides, I don't know how to write the ID of my photo. I am trying. Please tell me how where could I type my photo ID.

Comment: Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How can I load image with this code? ***icons_dict.load("custom_icon", os.path.join(icons_dir, "icon.png"), 'IMAGE')***

Comment: What is my icon ID. How can I figure it out?

Comment: Take your time and read the answer over there carefully. If that doesn't help for whatever reason, I'd recommend edit your question and explain *in detail*, what you have tried, why this does not work for you and share your code, see the link above.

Comment: I have read that question. but I still don't know why and how I can make a icon. I even copy the code that the answer provide, and it's not work. I wonder how and where can I type the ID of my icon

Comment: Just a register issue for blender 2.8x versions. The error has nothing to do with the actual question... Anyway, updated the code for 2.8+ versions. You're welcome. BTW: If you had read the "answer", you might know that you do not have to set any ID.

Comment: @brockmann in hindsight the JJN example is a little poor in that it is using the filepath of the current text in the text editor as the icon file path.  Possibly craves a new answer more in line with template examples.  Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62304/custom-icons-script-path-register

Comment: Agree @batFINGER What do you think about replacing that by the actual blend file path?

Comment: Do not agree on re-opening this q. @batFINGER

Comment: If you want a mwe, I'd suggest we comment out that line and just add `script_path = bpy.data.filepath`... What do you think? @batFINGER